# Laravel 5 Validation accept comma separated string with max 4 numbers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Laravel 5 Validation accept comma separated string with max 4 numbers

Example-

```
1.  1,2,3,4              ---  Accepted

2.  1,2                  ---  Accepted

3.  1,2,3,4,5            ---  Rejected
```

**Note:** I can Achieve this task by first convert the string to array and then validate the request, But i am looking for a Best approach to solve the same.

Comment: That's good to know.

Comment: Don't know how to do that, Help me in the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate it with this in your controller:

```
$this->validate(Request::instance(), ['field_name'=>['required','regex:/^\d+(((,\d+)?,\d+)?,\d+)?$/']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [custom Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules) for this.

```
php artisan make:rule MaxNumbers
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class MaxNumbers implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return count(explode(',', $value)) < 5;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be max 4 numbers.';
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
use App\Rules\MaxNumbers;

$request->validate([
    'field_name' => ['required', new MaxNumbers],
]);
```

Comment: some regex to check for actual numbers there won't harm

Comment: is custom validation is in Laravel 5.6 ?

Comment: No, it is with 5.2 as well, you can find more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex rule:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'field_name' => 'regex:/^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+){0,3}$/'
]);
```